# Passing multiple parameters to .Net WebApi Controllers using Volley in Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebAPI method in Controller as below

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Part))]
 public IHttpActionResult PostPart(Part part, string yearsIDList)
{

}
```

where `Part` is a `DTO` Class` and 'yearsIDList' is simple string.

I would like to call this method from `Android` using `Volley` as below

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,new JSONObject(params), this,this
            ) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                   // stub code, I removed it for security reasons before posting on SO
                }
            };
```

`params` contains all data for `Part`. I want to know how to pass multi parameters in a `POST` method from `android`. I want to pass `yearsIDList` too.

Answer (score 0):

As is is accepting `Paramters`, you can create `JsonObject` with both `parameters` and need to pass it as in

```
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                JSONObject part= new JSONObject(params);
                params.put("part",part.toString());
                params.put("yearsIDList","value");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);     
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,parameters, this,this
            ) {
               @Override
               public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                 // stub code, I removed it for security reasons before posting on SO
              }
            };
```

Comment: `getParams` will not be invoked using with `JsonObjectRequest`

Comment: now server volley giving `ServerError with statusCode 405`